# Remote Desktop to main screen

Tags: remote-desktop

I run a 14.04 Ubuntu machine connected over HDMI to my television. On that machine i do run VLC, which starts automatically. For controlling vlc I have "VLC Remote" on my android devices.

Now an then, i want to access the desktop remotely. I had TeamViewer installed, but when I exit the session, there always stays a that "thanks for using teamviewer" banner in front, which i don't get away without taking the mouse and hitting "OK"

I now look for an other way to remote connect to the main desktop in my Ubuntu. I've tried VNC and xrdb, but both connect to some other desktops.

Is there a remote desktop tool which allows me to see the same desktop as on the regular Ubuntu screen? (Same picture in remote as on monitor?)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which desktop environment you're using, but you can install krfb, which lets you connect to your desktop.

[image: krfb main window]

I'm not sure if this will work with unity (since this is a KDE-based application), but it does share your main screen, and does not start a "second" VNC session. It also lets you connect without having to interact after the session ends.